# insertBefore on multiple elements only work with the last one

Tags: javascript, required, appendchild, textnode

I have a form with lots of input elements and there's nothing telling the user which fields are required. The problem is that I don't have access to its HTML code.

So I'm writing this JavaScript:

```
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");  
var newItem = document.createElement("LI");  
var textnode = document.createTextNode("(*)");  
newItem.appendChild(textnode);  
for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {  
        if(allInputs[i].hasAttribute('required') == true){  
          allInputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, allInputs[i]);  
        }  
}
```

**Result:** it adds (*) before the last input only. I've tried running this code on the browser console line by line, and I've noticed that it adds the text on a input and erases the previous one.

I'm not a web developer and I'm using examples I found on the internet, so this is tricky for me :/

Answer (score 2):

You are actually adding the element next to each input. But since you are referencing the same `newItem` it just moves the element from one location to the next instead of creating a new element at that location.

Use [`cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to make a new copy of your element that you can place at each location.

```
allInputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newItem.cloneNode(true), allInputs[i]);
```

Comment: The `cloneNode()`method is the right answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new `li` only once, before the loop starts, so every time you `insertBefore` you're removing the `li` from its previous location and putting it in the new location.

If the new element only has one child node, and that child node is a text node, it's less verbose to simply assign to `textContent`.

Create a new `li` on each iteration instead:

```
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (let i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {  
  if(allInputs[i].hasAttribute('required') == true){  
    const newItem = document.createElement("LI");  
    newItem.textContent = '(*)';
    allInputs[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, allInputs[i]);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addAsterisk(node){ 
    var newItem = document.createElement("LI");  
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("(*)");  
    newItem.appendChild(textnode);
    node.parentNode.insertBefore(newItem, node);
}

var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input"); 

for (var i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++) {  
        if(allInputs[i].hasAttribute('required') == true){
          addAsterisk(allInputs[i]);
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you want to place your mark, but adding it in a `<li>` will make the mark appear on a new line.

Personally I would add the mark on the side of the input, like this:

```js
const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[required]");
const addMark = x => x.parentNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode("*"));
[...allInputs].forEach(addMark);
```

```html
<ul>
<li><label>First name <input required/></label>
<li><label>Second name <input/></label>
<li><label>Email<input type="email" required/></label>
<li><label>Information <input/></label>
</ul>
```